# 'agree a number ... to one mischief' (1655 UK)

Tags: meaning-in-context, seventeenth-century-english

[Source:](http://www.thomas-hobbes.com/works/elements/21.html) Paragraph 2, Chapter XX, *De Corpore Politico*, 1655, by Thomas Hobbes

> For multitude, though in their persons they run together, yet they concur not always in their designs. For even at that time when `men are in tumult`, though they **agree** a number of them to ***one mischief***, and a number of them to another; yet, in the whole, they are amongst themselves in the state of hostility, and not of peace

While writing [this ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/54270/8712), I tried to read some examples on Google Books which yielded the above. Which definition of  **agree** matches?

I tried [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/4146?rskey=4w819R&result=2&isAdvanced=false). I guessed definitions 15, and the obsolete 16 and 17, which I don't replicate here because none match.    I'm guessing:
it doesn't make sense to harmonise or reconcile  `men .. in tumult` to ***one mischief***.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the cited usage matches OED definition II 3c *intr. With **to**. To consent to a proposal, condition, etc.*, which OED has provided a link to (even though non-subscribers won't be able to access this).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yet how does one choose the right definition, if one's confused? The OED overwhelms me often.

Comment: I think sometimes you assume a level of *precision* that English doesn't actually have (there's also *change over time*, given we're looking at a 350-year-old text here). I suspect (but don't *know*) that to Hobbes "agree" there carries more the sense of "come to a consensus [in support of a proposal]" *as a group*, rather than "consent [each as an individual]". But this is a fine distinction - the general sense is all you really need to understand the point he's making (that the mob/common people form various subgroups with no overall coherence/agreement).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Maybe you're right. I'll try to mind this assumption. I just wanted to identify the right definition before settling this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> men are in tumult,

That is, there is disagreement among all the men.

> though they agree a number of them to one mischief,

One group ("a number of them") has agreed to commit some act of mischief

> and a number of them to another;

Another group has agreed to commit some *other* act of mischief

Does that help?